# Google pre-launch stability errors for: com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin

Tags: android

I'm trying to submit an update to an existing app to production, but I seem to be failing in the prelaunch for one specific device on on android sdk 26. I can reproduce this on emulation of sdk 26. The testing video seemed to just show the automated testing opening and closing the app and clicking around for about 5 minutes. I didn't seem to see any errors in the app itself.

I'm received several errors and all seem to be related to items related to com.google.android.apps.mtaas .

My app doesn't use any DeviceAdmin features so I'm not sure where these are coming from. Also, after looking at the full logcat file none of these process ID's match with the process ID's of my running app, and some of these seem to occur in the logs before I see much activity from the testing opening/closing my app.

Does anyone have any clue where to begin? I can't seem to recreate it, and without any hint to how they might relate to my code(if they do at all) I can't properly attempt to implement any fix.

I've seen numerous threads about false positives related to the prelaunch reports generating false positivies, but I'm not sure if that's the case here or not.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.HideApps
Process: com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin, PID: 14692
java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin ComponentInfo

{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.DeviceAdminReceiver}
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1958)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1904)
at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.isApplicationHidden(IDevicePolicyManager.java:8952)
at android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.isApplicationHidden(DevicePolicyManager.java:7466)
at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.HideApps.onStart(HideApps.java:63)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2106)
```

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin, PID: 14836
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception thrown in onCreate() of ComponentInfo

{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.ToggleUserRestriction}
: java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin ComponentInfo

{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.DeviceAdminReceiver}
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6050)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.DeviceAdminReceiver}
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1958)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1904)
at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.setUserRestriction(IDevicePolicyManager.java:8542)
at android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.addUserRestriction(DevicePolicyManager.java:7339)
at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.ToggleUserRestriction.start(ToggleUserRestriction.java:49)
at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.ToggleUserRestriction.onCreate(ToggleUserRestriction.java:22)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6047)
... 8 more
```

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin, PID: 14959
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception thrown in onCreate() of ComponentInfo

{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.SetUpdatePolicy}
: java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin ComponentInfo

{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.DeviceAdminReceiver}
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6050)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.DeviceAdminReceiver}
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1958)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1904)
at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.setSystemUpdatePolicy(IDevicePolicyManager.java:9956)
at android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.setSystemUpdatePolicy(DevicePolicyManager.java:7970)
at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.SetUpdatePolicy.start(SetUpdatePolicy.java:51)
at com.google.android.apps.mtaas.deviceadmin.SetUpdatePolicy.onCreate(SetUpdatePolicy.java:34)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6047)
... 8 more
```

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.android.apps.mtaas.tools, PID: 23437
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate instrumentation ComponentInfo

{com.google.android.apps.mtaas.tools/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.tools-kyrqBrU_34KhOurU1Kfvdg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.tools-kyrqBrU_34KhOurU1Kfvdg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5995)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.tools-kyrqBrU_34KhOurU1Kfvdg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.google.android.apps.mtaas.tools-kyrqBrU_34KhOurU1Kfvdg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5993)
... 8 more
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?